# Koma Classes: Add to Header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

The running headers for my document appear too high on the page. The manual isn't clear as to where the switch should go (after scrlayer-scrpage? or as a class option?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,9pt,BCOR=15mm,headheight=20.5pt]{scrbook}
```

has no effect.

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}[headheight=20.5pt]
```

has no effect either.

What is the proper syntax?

Manual page 45:

In some cases it is useful to be able to specify the header height not in lines but directly as a length. This is accomplished with the alternative option **headheight**. All lengths and sizes that LATEX understands are valid for height.

Comment: Do you use the `geometry` package or any other means to control the size of margins?

Comment: No. Supposedly the geometry package doesn't play nice with Koma classes.

Comment: I am asking that because because to me the KOMA manual describes `headheight` as a way to control the amount of vertical space that may be used for a header rather than its position on the page, which depends on the calculation of the page's margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package in koma-script, but you should specify the `usegeometry` option to make it work together nicely.

The parameters that are relevant are `tmargin` (or `top`) that specify the space between the top of the paper and the headerline, and `headsep` which is the space between the headerline and the text. I don't know which one you want to change, but `headheight` is the wrong one, as it specifies how much vertical space is reserved for the headerline.

This should give you an indication:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,9pt,BCOR=15mm,usegeometry]{scrbook}

\usepackage[headsep=1cm,tmargin=1cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
```